# Correct rule is not getting executed on my remote ubuntu machine

Tags: rules, rasa

I've developed a rasa chatbot and it is working perfectly fine in my local windows machine, but it is not working properly on my remote ubuntu machine. The action "action_when_next_ekadashi_bang" is executed successfully but when the intent "parana_start_and_end" is executed, the "action_paran_start_and_end" is executing rather than "action_banglore_paran_timing".

- rule: When is next ekadashi Banglore
  steps:

  - intent: banglore
  - action: action_when_next_ekadashi_bang
- rule: Parana timings in Banglore
  steps:

  - action: action_when_next_ekadashi_bang
  - intent: parana_start_and_end
  - action: action_banglore_paran_timing
- rule: Parana timings
  steps:

  - intent: parana_start_and_end
  - action: action_paran_start_and_end

This is my rules file and in my config file, I'm using the default configuration. Please give your valuable suggestions. Do I need to make changes in my rules.yml file or config.yml file?